# Does JNA allow passing 2-dimensional arrays to C by reference or value?

Tags: java, c, arrays, jna

I have a java web app that has a method in one of the classes that finds duplicate rows for an array, removes them, and passes the total rows back to the calling program. This method takes up to 50 seconds to execute when the app is deployed. I wanted to see if using C for it would make it substantially faster. I was wondering if the JNA for using native C code allows passing 2-dimensional integer arrays (by reference or value - reference would be better, since the web app needs the updated array) to a native C library method (I'm on Linux since my web hosting for the app is Linux). Any help, insight, comments, suggestions, examples, or links, would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here's my C code: (The Java method implements the same code without the method declaration; any suggestions on how to make that faster would be welcome).

```
int  find2(int matches[][4], int total)
    {
        int i, j, k, l, matches_count;

        i = 1;

        while (i <= total)
        {

            j = i + 1;

            while (j <= total)
            {

                matches_count = 0;

                for (k = 1; k <= 2; k++)
                {

                    for (l = 1; l <= 2; l++)
                    {

                        if (matches[i][k] == matches[j][l])
                        {

                            matches_count += 1;

                        }

                    }

                }

                if (matches_count == 2)
                {

                    matches[i][3] += 1;

                    for (k = j; k <= (total - 1); k++)
                    {

                        for (l = 1; l <= 3; l++)
                        {

                            matches[k][l] = matches[k + 1][l];

                        }

                    }

                    j -= 1;

                    total -= 1;

                }

                j += 1;

            }

            i += 1;

        }

        return total;
    }
```

Comment: There's no such thing as passing an array by value in C.  All explicit array parameters are passed by address.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I kind of knew that but wans't completely sure if you could do it.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially need memory shared between your Java and native code.  There are several ways of doing this:

- direct byte buffer (NIO)
- `com.sun.jna.Memory`
- primitive array

In all three cases, you basically have a block of memory, and it's up to your native code to index into it in a manner compatibly to how your Java code accesses it (row-major, column-major, or some other format).  To your native code, all three types appear as a pointer to a buffer.

The primitive array gives you the easiest access from the Java side, but may incur performance hits if the data has to be copied before and after passing it on to the native code.  The primitive array may be stored differently by the VM (not all contiguously).

The direct buffer and JNA `Memory` use native memory, and don't incur any copying costs until you read data out of the buffer.  You should test in your own environment which one is easier to use and/or more performant.

Comment: I was able to bypass that method completely by checking for duplicate rows while initially populating the array. Got it down to 3 seconds for the whole function to complete, including populating the array, sorting, and outputting to a .jsp page. Thanks for the insight anyway.